# AutoCompleteTextView hide auto complete suggestions

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have an AutoCompleteTextView widget on the view. if it has input focus and I'm trying to change the text in there with:

```
txtField1.setText("test");
```

I'm getting suggestions list appears on the screen. How do I hide it? is it possible to update the text not showing suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to set the text then give the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest some methods

1)If you want to make "test" like hint of autocomplete textView then do like this,

```
 txtField1.setHint("test");
```

2)If you need to fill up the text view with "test" and also need to prevent the suggestion increase the threshold level for auto complete textview ,

```
   txtField1.setThreshold(5);
```

if you use threshold it will show suggestion after 5 character (according to the code posted in above line). If you need try to set different word and also try to avoid suggestion , change the threshold dynamically based on length of string.

Comment: allright, my point is: when somebody clicks on the table row, some string data gotta be populated in to the textView. i dont feel good clicking on the table and getting all the results behind autocomplete list.

Comment: I mean, I want to change the text. no user action is taken at the moment i'm updating the text, thus I don't want autocomplete to show up.

Comment: Isn't there a way hide suggestions the first time without setting a larger threshold ?

Answer (score 46):

I'll leave this here, in case someone needs it in the future, like I did.

```
yourAutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
```

will make the list with suggestions disappear from the screen.

Comment: this is perfect answer which i have expected